# Angular 2 and i18n

Tags: angular, internationalization

I've seen in the github-repo of Angular 2, that a lot of i18n-features have been developed so far. But I don't find any information about using them.

Are there descriptions or sample-projects that show how to use those features?

Best wishes,
Manfred

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - internationalisation (i18n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506628/angular-2-internationalisation-i18n)

Comment: Have you used i18n yet? what features are you (still) missing? just curious

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, i18n for angular2 is not done yet. So far, the best alternative is [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate).